# SurveyMonkey iOS SDK - Error codes

Tags: ios, surveymonkey

I am using SurveyMonkey iOS SDK,

I have the following delegate method,

```
- (void)respondentDidEndSurvey:(SMRespondent *)respondent error:(NSError *) error {
}
```

From this, I need to validate the error if it is from the server side or client side. How can I solve this.

Kindly do the needful on this.

Note:
SMError.h:

```
+ (SMError *)sdkServerErrorFromCode:(NSInteger)statusCode errorObject:(NSError *) error;

+ (SMError *)sdkClientErrorFromCode:(NSInteger)statusCode errorObject:(NSError *) error;
```

Answer (score 0):

Govinda, those methods are internal to the SDK and are used to return errors by the SDK -- they're not meant to be used externally.

The NSError * returned by the respondentDidEndSurvey: method will have an error code that corresponds to the list of possible SDK errors [here](http://surveymonkey.github.io/surveymonkey-ios-sdk/Protocols/SMFeedbackDelegate.html#//api/name/respondentDidEndSurvey:error:) (e.g. error.code). The userInfo of the NSError * object also contains a description of the error - accessed via error.userInfo.

With that information, you should be able to handle any errors returned by the SDK. Thanks!

Comment: Hello bleiken. The following code,                                                                      Error Domain=SurveyMonkeySDK_ServerError Code=5 "(null)" UserInfo={SurveyMonkeySDK_Error=There was a problem retrieving the user's response to this survey., NSUnderlyingError=0x160a40500 {Error Domain=SurveyMonkeySDK_ServerError Code=7 "(null)" UserInfo={SurveyMonkeySDK_Error=Response limit exceeded for your plan. Upgrade to access more responses through the SDK.}}}  Here I have two codes which telling the error. May I know why it is showing two codes. At which code I have to validate.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean If the SDK is returning 2 error codes, then it means you've submitted two survey responses. If you're seeing Error Code 7, it means you're not on an upgraded account, so you can just ignore that error entirely. Basically, you should only be worried about SDK errors if you're on an upgraded account.